# Draggable not working correctly in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Whenever you attempt to drag an image that you need to scroll down to see (anything not visible on first load) the image gets shot up to the top of the page instead of staying with the cursor. This only happens in Chrome or Safari, works great in Firefox. I've tried methods outside of Draggable to fix this issue, but they just lead to additional problems.

Here's the simplest version of the desired code, I just can't find the right classes to use, but the answer must be somewhere [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

```
 $( "img" ).draggable({ stack: "img" });
```

I believe it's using jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js for the drag function.

So pretty much it doesn't know how to readjust the Y placement of an image outside of the initial window container, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: All your CSS and JS links return 404. Always check the console for errors first.

Comment: Ahh, completely my fault, just started testing it off a new server and uploaded the wrong files here, I'll fix this in a second

Comment: Oh I see the problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing image position from `relative` to `absolute` helps. But I think you should try to make draggable not an image, but its parent div. So:

```
$(".photo").draggable({ handle: "img", stack: ".photo" });
```

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try, the .photo div, for spacing purposes) is usually an oversized box so it allows you to drag off the image which I don't want.

Comment: Oh wait, that's what the handle is for haha

Comment: Wow, thank you that code worked although changing any other element to `absolute` doesn't allow the images to appear on the page.

Comment: You must use a _div_ component instead of _select_, there is a bug that Google does not want to fix [#860040](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=860040)